# Norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that send integer lattice points on integer

Tags: normed-spaces, book-recommendation

I've recently encountered a problem during an oral exam which consisted in finding all norms $N$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $N(\mathbb{Z}^2)\subseteq \mathbb{N}$

The result is that they are of the form :
$$ N(x,y) = \max_{1\le i\le n} |a_i x + b_i y|$$
With the constraint that the matrix formed by the coefficients $(a_i, b_i)$ is of rank 2.

I'm not asking for a proof as it is quite long, I am asking two things :

1) Can this result be generalized, and what are some interesting applications of this ?

2) Does anyone know any books or document on this notion ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A similar result holds in all dimensions.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $N$ is a norm on ${\mathbb R}^n$ which takes integer values on ${\mathbb Z}^n$. Then there are finitely many linear functions $\ell_i: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}, i\in I,$ with integer coefficients (i.e. *integer linear functions*),  such that
$$
N(x)= \max_{i\in I} \ell_i(x). 
$$
I do not have a reference for this and a proof is a bit long. The main step is the following:

**Lemma.** Let $B=N^{-1}([0,1])$ denote the unit ball of the norm $N$; let $S$ denote the boundary of $B$. For every $x\in S_{{\mathbb Q}}=S \cap {\mathbb Q}^n$, there exists an affine function $F: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}$ such that:

- $F(x)=1$.
- $F|_B \le N|_B$.
- The linear part $\ell$ of $F$ is an integer linear function.
- $\|\ell\|\le C$, where $C$ is a constant depending only on the norm $N$.

Once this lemma is proven, one uses density of $S_{{\mathbb Q}}$ in $S$ and the fact that there are only finitely many linear functions $\ell$ which can appear in this lemma, to conclude the proof of the theorem.

**Edit.** Regarding applications:

- Integer-valued norms (and the associated polyhedra, their unit balls) appear as important topological invariants. See for instance:

  1. [Thurston norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thurston_norm). (One  can find more references just by googling "Thurston norm".)
  2. Alexander norm, in [this paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/alex/alex.pdf).
- The existence of a discrete norm characterizes free abelian groups among all abelian groups:

Juris Steprāns, A Characterization of Free Abelian Groups, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 93, No. 2 (1985), pp. 347-349

Comment: With the geometric Hahn-Banach for any $x \in \Bbb{Z}^n$ we obtain a rational hyperplane leading to $\ell_x(y) = \sum_i a_i y_i, a_i \in \Bbb{Q},\ell(x) = N(x), \forall y, |\ell(y)|\le N(y)$. Are you saying the $a_i$ can be taken as integers ? If so we are done as for a finite set $\max_{x \in X} |\ell(x)|$ is a norm and there are only finitely many possible choices for the remaining $\ell_y, y \not \in X$

Comment: @reuns Why would the geometric HB yield rational coefficients?